# Unusual behavior with UIAlertViewController

Tags: swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a simple use of UIAlertViewController in which I pass button labels and action functions as arguments to a function named showAlert() which sets up and invokes the alert. I have action function in UIAlertAction in the `in` closure.

Unusual behavior: The action function gets executed as soon as the showAlert is executed instead of when the button is pressed.

The other issue is that the alert gets dismissed automatically when a button is pressed. I do not have dismiss statement.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func test1() {
        NSLog("test 1 executed")
    }




    @IBAction func show(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "Message",titleString: "A,B,C", function:test1())
    }
    func showAlert(title: String, message: String, titleString: String, function: ()) {
        let cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")
        let labels = titleString.components(separatedBy: ",")
        var actions = [UIAlertAction()]
        for label in labels {
            let a = UIAlertAction(title: label, style: .default) { action in
                function // executed as soon as showAlert is called!! 
                         // Expecting to be called when button is pressed
                NSLog("\(label) Pressed")

            }
            actions.append(a)
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions.
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .cancel) { action in
            NSLog("Cancel Button pressed.")
        }
        for action in actions {
            alertController.addAction(action)
        }
        // Add the actions.
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The response on the console is:
2017-05-11 11:55:15.593 AlertTest[5304:8818290] function executed
2017-05-11 11:55:25.287 AlertTest[5304:8818290] A Pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember this:

> **Adding ()s to the end of a method/function name will call the method. Remove the ()s to "refer" to that method/function.**

When you are doing this:

```
//                                                                           I mean this
//                                                                                 |
//                                                                                 v 
self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "Message",titleString: "A,B,C", function:test1())
```

You are calling `test` and using its return value as the argument to `showAlert`.

When that line is reached, `test()` is called first to evaluate its return value, then `showAlert` is called, hence the console output.

To refer to the method `test`, remove the `()`s.

```
self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "Message",titleString: "A,B,C", function:test1)
```

You also wrote the parameter type wrong. The type of function that takes no parameters and returns nothing should be `() -> Void`:

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String, 
    titleString: String, function: () -> Void) {
```

Also, in the alert closure, add the ()s to the function because you are now trying to call it:

```
let a = UIAlertAction(title: label, style: .default) { action in
    function() // Note the ()s
    NSLog("\(label) Pressed")

}
```

P.S. I don't think having all the buttons do the same thing is what you really want. I might be wrong though.

Comment: It works great. Thank you for the response and for an education.  No, I need to pass an array of functions but I am still struggling with right format. Reading Matt Neuburg's books. I really need to read up on closures.

Comment: @SyedTariq If you want to pass an array of functions, do `[() -> Void]` as the parameter type. But I personally think it's better to remove the whole `showAlert` function and manually add the `UIAlertAction`s.